# Cutting multiple objects

Tags: knife-tool

How do i cut all these small cylinders in stright line like this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An edit mode solution is by using the Bisect tool. Check the *Clear Outer* option to delete all vertices above the intersection plane:

[image: Bisect Tool]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean modifier on an arrayed object to do that:

[image]

[image]